# Sort an array of Objects and take N elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting, lodash

in a NodeJS service I have an array with objects that have these properties:

- batchType: string
- batchId: string (is a hash)
- transactionId: string (it's a hash)

This array stores all transactions of different types of batches.

Basically what I need is to be able to get N items from the array, but respecting certain rules:

1. At least get 1 item from each type of batch
2. At least get 1 item for each batchId
3. Sometimes the array could have only one type of batch

This is an example of the array:

```
let batchTransactionsArray = [
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: 'ffasf23' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '423' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: '534' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '86' },
  { batchType: 'type2', batchId: '111', transactionId: '97' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '1945' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: '79' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '79' },
  { batchType: 'type3', batchId: '425', transactionId: '1555645' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: 'fg5' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: 'jkh5' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '53j' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '4545' },
  { batchType: 'type2', batchId: '111', transactionId: '534l' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: 'jkg435' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: 'gfxg23' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '7asdt' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '222', transactionId: 'jdsa7' },
  { batchType: 'type3', batchId: '663', transactionId: '12423445' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '89saf6' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '12h3g' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '4h3k2hj' },
  { batchType: 'type3', batchId: '663', transactionId: '145' }
];
```

And an example of the output I need is (if I want 5 transactions from the array):

```
[{ batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: '534' },
 { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '86' },
 { batchType: 'type2', batchId: '111', transactionId: '97' },
 { batchType: 'type2', batchId: '111', transactionId: '534l' },
 { batchType: 'type3', batchId: '663', transactionId: '145' }
]
```

The criteria for sorting transactionIds would be random, there is no specific order to meet.

I was trying some lodash functions like groupBy and sortBy but no luck yet.

Here is a jsfiddle were I was playing with this: https://jsfiddle.net/20jh3ze7/

I really appreciate suggestions.

Comment: please add what you have tried and what does not work.

Comment: Thanks, I added a jsfiddle link

Comment: if you need lets say 5 items but theres more than 5 unqi ids do we go over the 5 max items or cut it off

Comment: Thank you, everyone who has made a collaboration, I'll review and test your suggestions and let you know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in steps:

- first add unique batchType elements (this meets the first criterion)
- then add unique batchId elements (this meets the second criterion)
- fill the array with remaining elements if there's still some space left (to go up to N elements)

To check for uniqueness, you can use a `Set`. Since you said you're using lodash, you can use `_.groupBy` to group your array by `batchItem` and `batchId` to get unique elements from each group.

```js
let batchTransactionsArray = [
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: 'ffasf23' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '423' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: '534' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '86' },
  { batchType: 'type2', batchId: '111', transactionId: '97' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '1945' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: '79' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '79' },
  { batchType: 'type3', batchId: '425', transactionId: '1555645' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: 'fg5' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: 'jkh5' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '53j' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '4545' },
  { batchType: 'type2', batchId: '111', transactionId: '534l' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: 'jkg435' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: 'gfxg23' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '7asdt' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '222', transactionId: 'jdsa7' },
  { batchType: 'type3', batchId: '663', transactionId: '12423445' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '89saf6' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '12h3g' },
  { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '4h3k2hj' },
  { batchType: 'type3', batchId: '663', transactionId: '145' }
];

function getNItems(array, N = 5) {
  if (N >= array.length) return array;
  let batchTypeGroups = _.groupBy(array, e => e.batchType),
      res  = new Set(), batchIds = new Set();
  
  // add unique batchTypes
  for (let [batchType, elements] of Object.entries(batchTypeGroups)) {
    if (res.size === N) break;
    let d = elements.find(e => !batchIds.has(e.batchId));
    if (d) {
      res.add(d);
      batchIds.add(d.batchId);
    } else {
      res.add(elements[0]);
    }
  }
  
  // add remaining unique batchIds
  let batchIdGroups = _.groupBy(array.filter(e => !batchIds.has(e.batchId)), e => e.batchId);
  for (let [batchId, elements] of Object.entries(batchIdGroups)) {
    if (res.size === N) break;
    res.add(elements[0]);
  }
  
  // add any remaining elements until we have N elements
  for (let e of array) {
    if (res.size === N) break;
    res.add(e);
  }
  
  return Array.from(res);
}

console.log(getNItems(batchTransactionsArray, 5));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I marked this as the correct answer because it meets all my needs, it's also easy to adjust and adapt to my project.

Comment: @VíctorVíquez cool. However, I think I had a bug. I've updated my answer with the correction (the `else` statement in the first `for` loop).

Comment: Yeah! You are right. I didn't see it before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this using lodash:

```js
let data = [ { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: 'ffasf23' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '423' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: '534' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '86' }, { batchType: 'type2', batchId: '111', transactionId: '97' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '1945' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: '79' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '79' }, { batchType: 'type3', batchId: '425', transactionId: '1555645' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: 'fg5' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '123', transactionId: 'jkh5' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '312', transactionId: '53j' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '4545' }, { batchType: 'type2', batchId: '111', transactionId: '534l' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: 'jkg435' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: 'gfxg23' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '7asdt' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '222', transactionId: 'jdsa7' }, { batchType: 'type3', batchId: '663', transactionId: '12423445' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '89saf6' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '12h3g' }, { batchType: 'type1', batchId: '111', transactionId: '4h3k2hj' }, { batchType: 'type3', batchId: '663', transactionId: '145' } ];

const customTake = (d, n) => {
  const roundRobinUnion = (arr) => {
    let res = []
    while (_.flatten(arr).length)
      _.each(arr, x => x.length ? res.push(_.remove(x, (y, i) => i == 0)) : null)
    return _.flatten(res)
  }
  const groups = _(d)
    .orderBy(['batchType', 'batchId'])
    .groupBy('batchType')
    .mapValues(x => _.values(_.groupBy(x, 'batchId')))
    .map(x => roundRobinUnion(x))
    .value()
  return _.take(roundRobinUnion(groups), n)
}

console.log(customTake(data, 3))
console.log(customTake(data, 5))
console.log(customTake(data, 6))
console.log(customTake(data, 8))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The idea is to group by both `batchType` and `batchId` and think about this issue as a round robin union. You go through each array index and do an union of each element.

If you care about the end sort order you can always do another `orderBy` at the end etc.

Here is a simple example of the `roundRobinUnion` idea:

```js
const data = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1],
  [5, 6]
]

const roundRobinUnion = (arr) => {
  let res = []
  while (_.flatten(arr).length)
    _.each(arr, x => x.length ? res.push(_.remove(x, (y, i) => i == 0)) : null)
  return _.flatten(res)
}

console.log(roundRobinUnion(data))  // [1,1,5,2,6,3]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: nice this is much cleaner than mine

Comment: This is cool, but how's this meeting the second requirement: *At least get 1 item for each batchId*?

Comment: Good question. Updated to address your concern.

Answer (score 0):

I think that for this type of problem we don't need extra dependencies.

We can do it by plain javascript :)

```js
let batchTransactionsArray = [
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "123", transactionId: "ffasf23" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "312", transactionId: "423" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "123", transactionId: "534" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "312", transactionId: "86" },
  { batchType: "type2", batchId: "111", transactionId: "97" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "312", transactionId: "1945" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "123", transactionId: "79" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "312", transactionId: "79" },
  { batchType: "type3", batchId: "425", transactionId: "1555645" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "123", transactionId: "fg5" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "123", transactionId: "jkh5" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "312", transactionId: "53j" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "111", transactionId: "4545" },
  { batchType: "type2", batchId: "111", transactionId: "534l" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "111", transactionId: "jkg435" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "111", transactionId: "gfxg23" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "111", transactionId: "7asdt" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "222", transactionId: "jdsa7" },
  { batchType: "type3", batchId: "663", transactionId: "12423445" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "111", transactionId: "89saf6" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "111", transactionId: "12h3g" },
  { batchType: "type1", batchId: "111", transactionId: "4h3k2hj" },
  { batchType: "type3", batchId: "663", transactionId: "145" }
];

const getUniqueBatches = () => {
  const uniqueBatches = [];

  batchTransactionsArray.forEach(b => {
    const batchByType = uniqueBatches.find(findBatchByType(b.batchType));
    const batchById = uniqueBatches.find(findBatchByBatchId(b.batchId));
    if (!batchByType || !batchById) {
      uniqueBatches.push(b);
    }
  });

  return uniqueBatches;
};

const findBatchByType = batchType => {
  return batch => {
    return batch.batchType === batchType;
  };
};
const findBatchByBatchId = batchId => {
  return batch => {
    return batch.batchId === batchId;
  };
};

console.log(getUniqueBatches());
```